# Which is correct : "{which were placed/placed} on buttresses ..."?

Tags: word-choice, exam-questions

> They wanted a series of statues to adorn the cathedral's exterior, (26) **placing** high on buttresses so that the art could be admired from afar.
>
> A) NO CHANGE
>   B) they were placed
>   C) which were placed
>   D) placed

This is an SAT question. I was unable to choose between answers C and D, so I wonder what is wrong with answer C?

Why can't "which" be used, though it also creates a dependent clause?

[image: screenshot of the question]

Comment: @LHC2012 Note that you shouldn't post pictures when you can write out your question. Pictures are not searchable and are not useful for archival purposes. Also text is easier for answerers to deal with. I see ColleenV has helped put your question in text. Please keep that in mind.

Comment: @L.Moneta I understand, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option C:

> They wanted a series of statues to adorn the cathedral's exterior, **which were placed** high on buttresses so that the art could be admired from afar.

However this does not make sense because they "wanted a series of statues", which means they did not yet exist. So you can't use "which were placed", which implies they were already built.
"which *would be* placed", indicates intention and would be OK.

Option D:

> They wanted a series of statues to adorn the cathedral's exterior, **placed** high on buttresses so that the art could be admired from afar.

This statement is OK, because "placed" just indicates the intended location based on their request.
So Option D is correct.

Comment: One thing I find interesting about the OP sentence is that it seems to conflate
two collocation patterns: _want something + past participle_  and _want something + to V_.

Answer (score 0):

My instructor told me that placing both "which were placed" and "placed" here can both make the sentence flow right in its meaning. However, the "subject" in the dependent clause is "a series of statues," which is of a singular form, and "were" is inconsistent here.

(I'm not a native speaker and I did not learn English Grammar in English, so I may not have used the correct terms, but I hope that you get the meaning to it. Good luck with your exams!)